# reset form with dynamic id

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Form looks like this:

```
<form id="yui_3_17_2_1_1533233239059_403"><input placeholder="Type to search…" type="text" spellcheck="false" value="boy" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1533233239059_402"></form>
```

The ID is dynamic. I need to clear its input text after page loads.

Do not know how to determine ID of dynamic ID.

```
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

I image something like that could be adapted.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `<input type="reset">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the only form in the page, it is as simple as that:

```
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $('form')[0].reset();
});
```